# Send a delayed reminder to a user

Tags: process-builder, scheduled-job

There is a field in our Account object which users cannot populate at the time of creation because they don't have the information. Sometimes the users don't go back and fill in the field. I would like to remind the users who have not yet filled in the field to do so, but I don't want to remind them if they have already done it.

Is this possible without Apex ? I know I could always have a scheduled action to be kicked off after creation in Process Builder, but I believe that action will be launched even if the user has already gone back and filled in the field. I don't believe it will re-evaluate at the time it is launched.

Could I maybe have the scheduled action be a launch of another Process which could then evaluate if the field has been populated, and if not send the email ?

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Time based wfr if field is blank base on x hours or days from created date

Comment: One question - but will it re-evaluate at the time of the delayed action ?

Comment: Read up on tbwfr. If you set criteria for when subsequently meets if the field is no longer blank the wfr will be canceled. It's all in the docs